How to constrain variables to fit a normal distribution
Given a time series $s_t$, I would like to define for each $t$ a perturbation $e_t$ such that the set of all $e_t$ "fits" (within some range) a normal distribution with mean $\mu=0$ and a given standard deviation $\sigma$. Possibly some other side constraints could be considered.
Is it possible to do this via (mixed integer) linear programming? (a non linear formulation would also be fine).
I was thinking maybe exploiting the fact that if $e_t$ follows a normal distribution, the $Q-Q$ plot should match the line with equation $y_t=\frac{e_t-\mu}{\sigma}$, where $y_t$ are the theoretical quantiles of a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

You have not stated any criteria for the $e_t.$ Why not just sample the $N(0, \sigma)$ distribution?

I could indeed sample it and add it to $s_t$. This would compute what I want "by construction". But I was wondering if  I could do it with (non) linear programming in case additional side constraints must be enforced. Is there a way to express $N(0,\sigma)$ in terms of constraints?

If you are asking whether there is a way to constrain model variables to fit a normal distribution, I'm not sure the question makes sense.

Yes that is my question, exactly. Why does it not make sense ? For example, if variables are binary, and imposing that approx half of the variables take value 0 and the other half 1 would constrain the model variables to fit a uniform distribution (?)

What about building a histogram using interval indicator variables, and constraining the distance from the expected histogram?

The issue is what you mean by "fit". Suppose your original time series has 10 observations and I give you values for $e_1, \dots, e_{10}.$ How would you decide if they "fit" a $N(0, 3)$ distribution?

You may use the PDF for Normal dist & then use the requirements for Normal to constraint the prob densities

@prubin I could decide if they fit a $N(0,3)$ distribution via a statistical test such as Kolmogorov-Smirnov, a normal probability plot, or any other "usual" normality test. These tests have there own criteria / distance to measure how well  the sample fits the theoretical distribution, and my idea was to minimise this distance.

@user1502040 yes that is interesting, would you mind expanding?

The $e_i$ values are not a random sample and, importantly, are not independent (since they are connected through the model constraints).
